# Terminology - function definition, function

Tags: terminology

Is there a distinction between a function definition (*not a declaration*) and a function? 
For me a function definition, is what gets defined by the programmer in the source code while the function it self is what we get after compilation. 
Is that a valid distinction?

Comment: This sounds very opinion-based to me. I don't think your definitions are necessarily wrong, I just don't see the point to having a distinction and would call both, a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there's a difference between a *function* and a *function definition*, otherwise we wouldn't bother having both terms. *Function* isn't just an abbreviation of *function definition*, they're separate terms that are used in different contexts.

For instance:

> The function definition for `readInput()` starts on line 34.

But:

> Input data are retrieved by the `readInput()` function.

It would be simply wrong to use *function definition* here. The *function definition* has a certain number of tokens, occurs at a specific place in the program and an be pointed out in a program listing. The *function* has a specific purpose, is active at specific times, and can be pointed out in a call stack or a memory segment.

Comment: forth, thank you.
Would it be correct to talk about "the function that starts at line 34"?

Comment: @Othman Yes, it's generally okay to use the shorter form of a longer term when the context makes clear the meaning. Only the opposite would be misleading.